# Save a domain model with related list data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, domain-driven-design

I have this entity:

```
public class Task
{
     public int Id {get;set;}
     public string Title {get;set;}
     public List<User> Users{get;set;}
}
```

What's the correct way to save this object with related data assuming in my action I get a task and a List with the users'id from my view:

```
public ActionResult Save(Task task, List<int> users)
{
     _repository.Save(task, users) //should I do it?
}

//or it?
public ActionResult Save(Task task, List<int> users)
{
     task.Users = _userRepository.GetAllUsers(users);
     _repository.Save();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It might be helpful to know what happens in the repository, but generally, the repository should not invoke any sort of behavior on entities. It should be responsible only for persistence and reconstitution. A typical workflow is as follows:

1. An entity is loaded by ID.
2. Behavior is invoked on the entity with required parameters passed.
3. Changes are committed - either with an explicit save on the repository or by committing an ambient transactions and unit of work.

This code can either be directly in the MVC controller or in an application service referenced by the controller.

Comment: So, you are saying to load users inside the action or use a service layer?

Comment: You can go either route. If you encapsulate this logic into an application service referenced by the controller it might be easier to reason about the API of your domain layer. On the other hand there is nothing wrong with placing that logic directly in the controller and bypassing the additional service layer - the controller could be the service layer.

Answer (score 1):

Question is unclear, but I would do the following. If you compare the two bits of code, the first bit will be more readable to the others and it's encapsulating all the setup works that user doesn't need to know.

However, I won't name it as "Save", it's not specific enough.

```
_repository.Save(task, users)
```

Comment: The method name is just a example :)

Comment: Yes, but to explain my question it's unnecessary.